# Error Nro: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, login

Soy nuevo en esto `php`, estoy siguiendo un tutorial pero me la estoy liando, a la hora de realizar mi consulta a la `BD` me sale este error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `username` = 'FerchuS' AND `password` =
>   '*******'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ventas_ci/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Controlador:

```
public function login()
{
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        $res = $this->Usuarios_models->login($username, sha1($password));

        if (!$res) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("Error","El usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos");
            redirect(base_url());
        }
        else{
            $data  = array(
                'id' => $res->id_usuario, 
                'nombre' => $res->nombre_usuario,
                'rol' => $res->rol_id_usuario,
                'login' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect(base_url()."dashboard");
        }
    }
```

Comment: dice que no reconoce la columna username, seguro que pertenece a esa tabla y esta escrito asi?

Comment: en donde llama a la columna username? por lo q yo pude entender username es la variable donde carga el usuario, la columna en realidad se llama username_usuario

Comment: ya entendi el error!!! gracias x la ayuda!!

Answer (score -1):

El error se encuentra en el modelo (que no estas mostrando):

```
$res = $this->Usuarios_models->login($username, sha1($password));
```

Porque estas mandando el usuario y la contrasena y seguramente estas haciendo un `select` de `username` cuando mencionas que tu campo es `username_usuario`, entonces ve a tu archivo `application/models/Usuarios_models.php` y busca la funcion `login()`, hay vas a cambiar el valor de `username` por `username_usuario`.

Comment: Muchas, gracias Eduardo.. me sirvio muchisimo tu ayuda. pero se me presenta otro problema al pasar la autenticacion del login, deberia llevarme a la pagina dashboard, pero me dice q no encuentra la pagina sabrias decirme cual deberia ser la ubicacion de este archivo?? o donde se configura cual es la raiz de directorio? me imagino q ahi deberia estar yo la enco en la carpeta /views/admin/dashboard.php no se si es correcto.. gracias!!